# 2010 15" Macbooks running Windows 10 without Bootcamp missing drivers

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, macbook

I have two 2010 15" Macbooks running Windows, one running Windows 8, and the other running Windows 10.
I have tried downloading the drivers from Bootcamp Support for both, but that didn't quite work.  For starters, the root executable would tell me something along the lines `"This computer is not running the correct version of Bootcamp for this Support Package"` (likely because there is no Bootcamp on either computer, and the drive of each computer is entirely Windows).
So, to get around this, I just ran each driver in each folder in the package individually and that mostly worked.

The problem is, the sound driver doesn't work on the Windows 8 Macbook, and the sound driver and the wifi driver doesn't work for the Windows 10 Macbook.

If anyone could point me to the right driver(s) or support package I need, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might answer your question. I cannot comment yet so I must answer to share this information. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant

Comment: Thanks, lost_, I just tried this but to no avail.  I ran the program, it said it installed all the drivers, but I still can't use my audio devices.  It still says there's no playback devices, and in Device Manager, the "High Definition Audio Controller" device says it encountered a problem.

Puzzlingly enough, when I plug in a usb mic/headphones, they work.  But on the on-board mic or speakers.

Comment: Huh @Deccadeo Youtube, that is peculiar. Here's something else that may work...

`Open Device Manager(as administrator)`
`Action > Add legacy hardware`
`Next`
`Install the hardware that I manually select`
`Sounds, video and game controllers`
`Choose the sound card (I believe that year was a Cirrus branded card, may be wrong though)`
`Continue through the installation of it`
`Find the newly installed option in Device manager`
`Right click and Enable`

I'm not sure if this will work 100%, but it's worth a shot! We can search more if it doesn't :)

Comment: So, @lost_admin, I just tried that, but when I got to the part for choosing the sound card, I only see something from intel and something from realtek, neither of which worked.

Comment: @DeccadeoYoutube

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278518/macbook-pro-late-2011-sound-issues-in-windows-10-no-bootcamp

I just found this, and I know it is relating to a 2011, but after reading into it, it's looking like overall it's an issue with UEFI wont physically connect the sound card with windows. This seems like a very extensive work through to make it work. Or if you are ok with re-installing here is a guide to do it with legacy/BIOS/Hybrid MBR mode. https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/3rzxd5/guide_windows_10_bootcamp_on_unsupported_macs/

Comment: Well hot dang, that is way above my paygrade.  I just bought two USB sound cards; I can't tackle that.  Thanks for the explanation though!

Comment: @DeccadeoYoutube haha no worries man! Hope you don’t have any other issues!!